Mat Select not working well with chip list trigger
I'm trying to create a mat select with a chip list as the trigger. The selected options show up but the problem comes when the selected options need a second line. The chips started overflowing the form field, here is a picture and the code. What am I doing wrong?
What I have

What I want to achieve

My code in angular 14
<mat-form-field>
                            <mat-label>Manufacturing Days</mat-label>
                            <mat-select
                                (selectionChange)="selectedDay($event)"
                                formControlName="ManufacturingDays"
                                multiple>
                                <mat-select-trigger>
                                    <mat-chip-list>
                                        <mat-chip *ngFor="let days of selectedDays">
                                            {{ days.name }}
                                            <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
                                        </mat-chip>
                                    </mat-chip-list>
                                </mat-select-trigger>

                                <mat-option
                                    *ngFor="let day of daysOfWeek"
                                    [value]="day.value">
                                    {{ day.name | translate }}
                                </mat-option>
                            </mat-select>
                        </mat-form-field>

I've tried using exactly the code in this example (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-v9-mat-select-with-mat-chip-list?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-multiple-example.css) and haven't been able to have it work as in the example

Update
I ended up coming across this question while trying to search for an answer: Is it possible to use mat-select and mat-chips together?.
The problem is with Material 14, the trigger box has to be specifically set to "fit-content"
Like this:
.mat-select-trigger {
   height: fit-content;
}


I had the same issue and I ended up solving it by adding a class to mat-select (for specificity) and then using that in the global styles.css file.
   <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Manufacturing Days</mat-label>
          <mat-select 
               class="your-class-name-here"
              (selectionChange)="selectedDay($event)"
               formControlName="ManufacturingDays"
               multiple>
               <mat-select-trigger>
               <mat-chip-list>
                 <mat-chip *ngFor="let days of selectedDays">
                {{ days.name }}
               <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
               </mat-chip>
             </mat-chip-list>
           </mat-select-trigger>

         <mat-option
           *ngFor="let day of daysOfWeek"
              [value]="day.value">
               {{ day.name | translate }}
         </mat-option>
       </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>

And in your global css file
   .your-class-name-here {
    .mat-select-trigger {
      display:flex;
      align-items: flex-end;
      cursor:pointer;
      position:relative;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      width:100%
    }
  }

